# Why is My Django Form Executed Twice?

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

Can someone explain to me why form 2 executed twice?  In another word, I would see 2 print statements, "Hello from form 2," in the console.

The first print statement occurred after I clicked "Submit" from form 1.  Second print statement comes after the second "Submit" I clicked from form 2.  How do I make it to only print once?

**views.py**

```
def form1 (request):

    NameFormSet = formset_factory (NameForm, formset = BaseNodeFormSet, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        name_formset = NameFormSet (request.POST, prefix = 'nameform')

        if name_formset.is_valid ():
            data = name_formset.cleaned_data
            request.session ['data'] = data

            return HttpResponseRedirect ('form2')
        else:
            name_formset = NameFormSet (prefix = 'nameform')

     context = {'name_formset': name_formset}

     return render (request, 'nameform/form1.html', context)


def form2 (request):

    data = request.session ['data']
    print ('Hello from form 2')    # <====  This statement printed twice in the console

    CheckBoxFormSet = formset_factory (CheckBox, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        checkbox_formset = CheckBoxFormSet (request.POST, prefix = 'checkbox')

        if checkbox_formset.is_valid ():
            for i, form in enumerate (checkbox_formset.cleaned_data):
                data [i].update (form)      # Join cleaned data with original data

            del request.session ['data']
            context = {'data': data}
            return render (request, 'nameform/success.html', context)

            checkbox_formset = CheckBoxFormSet (prefix = 'checkbox')

     context = {'checkbox_formset': checkbox_formset, 'data': data}
     return render (request, 'nameform/form2', context)
```

**Update 1:**
The "print" statement is actually a backend method that processes the data obtained from form 1 and display it in form 2.  Leaving where it is now would cause that method to process the information twice.  I have no issue or error doing it this way but it's unnecessary.

For example:

```
def form2 (request):

    data = request.session ['data']
    n, errors = getInfo (data)    # <====  This statement performed twice in the console
    if request.method = 'POST':
    ....    
        if checkbox_formset.is_valid ():
            for i, form in enumerate (checkbox_formset.cleaned_data):
                data [i].update (form)      # Join cleaned data with original data

            n.process_new_data (data, errors)
            del request.session ['data']

            context = {'data': data, 'errors': error}
            return render (request, 'nameform/success.html', context)

    else:
        checkbox_formset = CheckBoxFormset (prefix = 'checkbox')

    context = {'data': data, 'errors': error}
    return render (request, 'nameform/form2.html', context)
```

**Update 2**:
Since my explanation is a little long, allow me address Ale question here.

Yes, I fully understand why it processed twice.  To briefly answer your question, putting getInfo inside 'POST' will give me a context, unbound error because of the context "errors" dictionary doesn't exist in the first redirect.

```
context = {'data': data, 'errors': errors}
```

I'd to update my post so that I can explain why I can't use your method.  GetInfo takes the data from form1, processes it, and passes it on to form 2 to display.  I could do all that in form1 but then I would have to redo it in form2 because form2 will not know what 'n' or 'errors' is without passing it through sessions.  I'm just trying to see if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: first print occurs on the redirect, when there is actually a GET to form2 second when you do the POST. If you put pirnt after the if request... then you'll get it only once.

Comment: Yes that would work for a print statement and thank you for addressing my question.  The real problem is the "print" statement is an actual backend program that display the processed "data".  If I move it inside the "if request" statement then form 2 will be unbounded by context statement.  I've updated form 2 to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I think you need to reword your question, @Ale has addressed this: _"Can someone explain to me why form 2 executed twice? In another word, I would see 2 print statements, "Hello from form 2," in the console."_

Comment: Sorry, you guys are fast.  I just edited the original post to make it a bit more clearer.

Comment: @dreamzboy as I said it will be executed twice for the same reason. First GET the form, the POST data in the form because of the redirection you have in in form1. When do you want to use getInfo? Why do you need to execute it once? If you only want to getInfo on post, just use it after you check that the form is valid.

Comment: I've answered to your question in update 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form2 view is run twice, once as a redirect from form1 which creates the form and renders the template, missing the `if request.method == 'POST'` part as this time around the request is a 'GET'.

When you submit form2 back to the same view method it prints the line you indicate again, this time the code in the if block executes as the request is a 'POST'.

The key is this line that redirects to the form2 view:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect ('form2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this by including the stacktrace to you print statements:

```
import traceback
print ''.join(traceback.format_stack())
```