# How to Prevent a Redirected Django Form from Executing Twice?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

My form2 is executing twice due to HttpResponseRedirect and from 'POST'.  How do I prevent that from happening?  Is it even possible?

What I've tried:

- Process and render "getInfo" from form 1 and display it in form2.  While this may work but I'll still end up going through the "getInfo" again in form2 to be able to use the returned variable.
- Putting "getInfo" inside the if request.method will create an error because getInfo will need to be executed to obtain the returned errors variable.

Any suggestion is definitely welcomed.

**Update**
I've raised a similar question regarding "Why My Django Form Executed Twice?" and it was answered.  I didn't want to create a bigger confusion by adding more questions on top of it.  I created this as a follow-up question on how to actually solve it.

views.py

```
def form1 (request):

        NameFormSet = formset_factory (NameForm, formset = BaseNodeFormSet, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

        if request.method == 'POST':

            name_formset = NameFormSet (request.POST, prefix = 'nameform')

            if name_formset.is_valid ():
                data = name_formset.cleaned_data
                request.session ['data'] = data

                return HttpResponseRedirect ('form2')
         else:
                name_formset = NameFormSet (prefix = 'nameform')

         context = {'name_formset': name_formset}

         return render (request, 'nameform/form1.html', context)


def form2 (request):

        data = request.session ['data']
        n, data, errors = getInfo (data)    # <====  This statement executed twice in the console

        CheckBoxFormSet = formset_factory (CheckBox, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

        if request.method == 'POST':

            checkbox_formset = CheckBoxFormSet (request.POST, prefix = 'checkbox')

            if checkbox_formset.is_valid ():
                for i, form in enumerate (checkbox_formset.cleaned_data):
                    data [i].update (form)      # Join cleaned data with original data

                n.processData (data, errors)  # <=== n object will be used from getInfo

                del request.session ['data']
                context = {'data': data}
                return render (request, 'nameform/success.html', context)

        else:
                checkbox_formset = CheckBoxFormSet (prefix = 'checkbox')

        context = {
                    'checkbox_formset': checkbox_formset,
                    'data': data,
                    'errors': errors,   # <==== getInfo needed to execute first to display errors messages
        }
         return render (request, 'nameform/form2.html', context)


def getInfo (data):
    # Do something with data

    return (n, data, errors)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is My Django Form Executed Twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108972/why-is-my-django-form-executed-twice)

Comment: I raised that question but it was already answered and I didn't want to confuse more people so I started a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Should the `else:` statement be less indented to align with `if request.method == POST:`?  Also, where does getInfo come from?  In the version of django I'm using (1.7) errors are an attribute on the formset after calling `is_valid()`.

edit: further information

OK so your `getInfo` function runs twice because HttpResponseRedirect actually returns a 302 response to the browser with the new address, which the browser then GETs.  Then when the user submits the form the browser POSTs the data to the same view.  Since `getInfo` runs at the start of your view before any GET/POST conditional check, it runs both times.  If you just want to delegate returning a response to another view function, you can call it directly, don't return a redirect.

Without knowing any more about your program this is as much as anyone can tell you.

Some more points:

1. `getInfo` sounds like it should be a 'safe' function that doesn't mutate its input or have any side effects, so running it twice shouldn't be a problem.  If it does either of those things, you ought to rename it at least.
2. If the results of `getInfo` aren't expected to change between the GET and the POST request then you can move it into the form1 view function and store the results in `session['data']`.  If it is expected to change, or you need to know if it does change, then you have no option but to run it twice anyway, unless there is some conditional you can check without running it to know if it will change.
3. Finally, form validation shouldn't be in the view if possible, keep it in your form class.  There are hooks in django's form classes for whatever kind of validation you could want to do on submitted data.  As a general rule, try to work within the framework, in the way it was designed to be used.  This approach, as opposed to constructing a Rube-Goldberg machine out of the scavenged parts of many libraries taped together, will save you a lot of effort in the long run, as the library author and you will be working in the same direction.

Comment: Yes, it's on the same indentation as request.method='POST' in my code.  It was indented by accident in Stack's editor.  getInfo is being called as a method in views.  See updated post.

Comment: Thank you for an incredible detail tips and advices.  I'm still confused by, "If you just want to delegate returning a response to another view function, you can call it directly, don't return a redirect."  I used render and it works but it didn't "redirect" to form2.  HttpResponse seems to only work with string.  What should I use if I want to call form2 directly?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem!  Yes HttpResponse only takes a string and (I think) wraps it to go through django's middleware and get sent back to the client.  Using django it's easy to forget that this is just python and these are just functions.  To delegate to the "form2" view, you can just call it with the request, same as your urlconf does.  So, where you currently return a redirect, just put `return form2(request)`.  Honestly though I doubt that's what you really want to do, but it is possible.

Comment: I see what you mean. It's simple enough; however, I get the "ManagementForm data is missing" because form1's url didn't redirect to form2 where the checkbox form takes place.  Plus, everything is executing under form1 since it just calls the method.  I guess I'm stuck with having it ran twice.